# Azure DevOps - Ignore Unit Test

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am attempting to get a Azure Devops pipeline to ignore tests that have a particular attribute.. but they are still being run..

this is my test:

```
[TestCategory("DoNotRunOnBuild"), TestMethod]
public async Task DHL_LoadInvoice()
{
    Code goes here...
}
```

and in the yaml file i have this:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
  platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  arguments: '--filter "TestCategory!=DoNotRunOnBuild"'
```

I am obviously misunderstanding the posts i have read or done something wrong...

Can anyone offer any help please?

Comment: Hi @Trevor Daniel, have you checked my answer below? Whether it works for you? If it works, in order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer below according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `testFiltercriteria` instead of `arguments` in VSTest@2 task. For example, `testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=DoNotRunOnBuild'` . See more info from [VSTest@2 - Visual Studio Test v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines#:%7E:text=testFiltercriteria%20%2D%20Test%20filter%20criteria).